# How to get coordinates QScrollArea child widget?

Tags: qt

How to get coordinates QScrollArea child widget?

[image: The parent scroll widget with a child widget.]

```
mainWindow::mainWindow( QWidget *parent)
{
    // class PaintWidget:public QScrollArea
    PaintWidget *painter = new PaintWidget( this, &manager);
    setCentralWidget( painter );

    //some code
}

PaintWidget::PaintWidget( QWidget *parent, plugin::PluginsManager *manager):
   painter(manager, this)
{
   // RPW painter;
   // class Painter:public QGLWidget
   setWidget( &painter );
   setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );

   //some code
}
```

Comment: What does `painter->pos()` return? Isn't it its coordinates in the parent's coordinate system?

Comment: it return QPoint(0,0)

Comment: Is it wrong? Or you need global coordinates?

Comment: I need to get coordinates of the QWidget relative to the QScrollArea. It's actually not 0,0 (as you can see it on the image, a link to which is in the question).

Comment: If `PaintWidget` is a QScrollArea, then I think you need to call `QPoint p = painter->widget()->pos();`.

Answer (score 0):

`QWidget::pos()` is what you're looking for. It applies in all cases, `QScrollWidget` does not require special treatment here at all.